# Why are read operations slower than write operations in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop

In cluster mode. We're running different I/O tests in Hadoop. And we noticed that writing data is faster than reading them. How to boost reading throughput to be as fast as the writing throughput. Is it a problem of configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it a problem of configuration?

**No**, it is actually not even a problem. I/O speeds for read and write operations can vary depending on the kind of benchmarks, on your filesystem settings, on your hardware settings, and on your configuration (if you have RAID, what kind of RAID it is and etc.).  This is completely normal and expected, although it is very hard to pinpoint accurately the cause of this.

---

I/O is a very broad topic with an extreme amount of details. The results you get from benchmarking can vary from way too many aspects, including the implementation of the I/O benchmarking the benchmark software is using, this is one of the reasons why you might get completely different results from different benchmarking software.

For example, without using the [O_DIRECT and O_SYNC](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) flags, you get a lot higher writing speeds than reading speeds. And if you use those flags for synchronous I/O operations, your write speed will be a lot slower than your write speed.

As another example, if you are using a RAID1 configuration, reading asynchronously from both disks will yield a huge boost in reading speed compared to the writing one, since you're limited to only writing on one of the disks, while you can read from both simultaneously.